# want to show data from api in service to controller 2

Tags: angularjs, http, service, controller

i am developing simple weather app in angular in which i have two controllers.
First controller contain form having two input city and country and search button call 
`ng-click=weathercheck()`

```
weatherapp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'commonservice', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($scope, commonservice, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.weathercheck = function (city, country) {
            commonservice.getweather(city, country);

        };
}])
```

here is second controller and route code

```
weatherapp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'main.htm',
        controller:'mainController'
    })
    .when('/result', {
        templateUrl: 'result.htm',
        controller: 'ResultController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/main'
    })
}])

weatherapp.controller('ResultController', ['$scope', 'commonservice', '$rootScope', function ($scope, commonservice, $rootScope) {
```

> here i want to access exact data from api call
>   getdata function make call again to the service as here i don't have 
>   city and country values it give me default data only

```
    $scope.place = commonservice.getweather(data);
    getdata();

    function getdata() {
        commonservice.getweather().then(function (data) {
            $scope.place = data;
        })

    }
}])
```

weathercheck method call method in service that have api call

```
function getweather(city, country) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
       return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+city+','+country +'&cnt=5&units='+unit)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                weatherresult = data;
                deferred.resolve(data);
                return weatherresult;
              //  $location.path('/result');
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                console.log('Error getting results');
           //     deferred.reject(err);
            })
        return deferred.promise;

    }
    return {
        getweather: getweather
    };



 <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.htm">
   this is first controller that contain form and search button
 </script>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="result.htm">
  this is the second controller where i want to show result 
 </script>
```

i stuck here for two days as this is my first angular app

Answer (score 0):

The `success` callback doesn't return to another `then`. Also you had 2 `return` in the `getWeather()` function

Try this:

```
function getweather(city, country) {

    return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + city + ',' + country + '&cnt=5&units=' + unit)
      .then(function (response) {
           console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error getting results');            
    }); 
}
return {
    getweather: getweather
};
```

Comment: how to use response.data in controller 2